# Нужны ли запятые

Tags: пунктуация

"Причем мало того(,) что эти фирмы поставляли некачественные продукты(,) — они еще и продавали их бюджету по серьезно завышенным ценам".

Скорее всего, в первом случае нет никакого интонационного разделения, поэтому запятая не нужна?
Какое правило действует во втором случае?

Comment: Я бы в первом случае запятую поставил, ибо присутствует *усиливающий элемент* - "причем". *Причем МАЛО того* (пауза) *что эти фирмы...*  
Во втором случае запятая вкупе с тире выглядит архаизмом - при сегодняшних-то лаконичных пунктуационных оформлениях)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы поставила знаки препинания так: "Причем мало того, что эти фирмы поставляли некачественные продукты — они еще и продавали их бюджету по серьезно завышенным ценам". Дерзкий прав, Союз причём здесь в роли усилительной частицы, а усилительные или ограничительные частицы - условие расчленения сложного союза.

Возможно поставить и запятую вместо тире, но тогда уйдёт интонационное подчёркивание придаточного, а это нежелательно, т.к. смысл предложения в возмущении фактами, изложенными в придаточном. Два знака  не требуется.Запятая и тире в качестве единого знака ставятся после ряда однородных придаточных,перед лексическим повтором и в периоде для разделения на 2 части.